# How to convert RSA private key from DER to PEM in JAVA?

Tags: java, rsa, private-key, pem, der

I have a RSA private key .der file (with a bunch of binary in it). How do I convert the file to PEM format in Java?

If I were to use openssl in command line, this is what I would do:

`openssl rsa -inform der -in privateKey.der -outform pem -out privateKey.pem`

The privateKey.pem result looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAyljm4IGV2JmL8amyTQz9nCSdtdJV+OGiiyefJasKuNEIVAyV
BzSNEUrJYL1LrAMM0cbenWh3M0I+RoQYfwo3J88fi/aLW5dbdU8bi001UZIeJnEB
...
...
lykp1jNHSXD8PoBNVD+pbY3zGCqH1OgPWd0/+IbMBp3Qo+HMp5Ku9w==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I heard that people say PEM is just Base64-encoded representation of DER plus certain header and footer. However, if I just do
`cat privateKey.der | base64`

I get different results from what openssl gave me:
`MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQDKWObggZXYmYvxqbJNDP2 ... ... GndCj4cynkq73`

Despite the head & footer, the PEM string is also not the same. Does anyone know why?

Are there any library to convert DER to PEM in Java like what openssl does? Been searching for a while but unfortunately, I didn't find anything that works. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There are many PEM formats, and OpenSSL supports about a dozen PEM *and* DER formats for private keys. The format written by `openssl rsa [-outform pem]` is the algorithm-specific PKCS1 appendix A format, with or without rfc1421-based encryption, and is labelled `RSA PRIVATE KEY`. The format written by `openssl pkey` or `openssl pkcs8 -topk8` is the algorithm-generic PKCS8 format, which defines its own encryption, and is accordingly labelled `PRIVATE KEY` or `ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY` -- note no RSA in either case; see [rfc7468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468). *Java crypto* e.g. `PrivateKey.getEncoded()` uses PKCS8 unencrypted, so if you got this DER from Java and converted it to base64 that's why you 'get different results'.
Also note PEM is base64 of DER **with line breaks every 64 chars** plus header and footer; without the line breaks it won't always work. For both of these see [PKCS#1 and PKCS#8 format for RSA private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958304/pkcs1-and-pkcs8-format-for-rsa-private-key) .

Your answer using BouncyCastle is a good solution if you have or can get Bouncy; bcpkix correctly handles most OpenSSL formats. If you want to do it without Bouncy, it is nearly the same as [How to encrypt RSA private key with PBE in PKCS#5 format in Java with IAIK JCE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630701/how-to-encrypt-rsa-private-key-with-pbe-in-pkcs5-format-in-java-with-iaik-jce) (mine) except without encryption, so leave out the middle block and change the PEM header slightly:

```
    // given [RSA]PrivateKey privkey, get the PKCS1 part from the PKCS8 encoding
    byte[] pk8 = privkey.getEncoded();
    // this is wrong for RSA<=512 but those are totally insecure anyway
    if( pk8[0]!=0x30 || pk8[1]!=(byte)0x82 ) throw new Exception();
    if( 4 + (pk8[2]<<8 | (pk8[3]&0xFF)) != pk8.length ) throw new Exception();
    if( pk8[4]!=2 || pk8[5]!=1 || pk8[6]!= 0 ) throw new Exception();
    if( pk8[7] != 0x30 || pk8[8]==0 || pk8[8]>127 ) throw new Exception();
    // could also check contents of the AlgId but that's more work
    int i = 4 + 3 + 2 + pk8[8];
    if( i + 4 > pk8.length || pk8[i]!=4 || pk8[i+1]!=(byte)0x82 ) throw new Exception();
    byte[] old = Arrays.copyOfRange (pk8, i+4, pk8.length);
    
    // write to PEM format (substitute other file if desired)
    System.out.println ("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");
    String b64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(old);
    for( int off = 0; off < b64.length(); off += 64 )
        System.out.println (b64.substring(off, off+64<b64.length()?off+64:b64.length()));
    System.out.println ("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");
```

I'd think carefully before calling this 'better' though. This is also similar to [Convert a X509 Public key to RSA public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685734/convert-a-x509-public-key-to-rsa-public-key) for publickey (also mine) and the reverse of [Reading a PKCS#1 or SPKI public key in Java without libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54238568/reading-a-pkcs1-or-spki-public-key-in-java-without-libraries) .

Answer (score 0):

After lots of digging... I found a way, but it looks redundant. Please let me know if you have better idea.

```
    // My private key DER file.
    byte[] privateKeyDerBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("tst/resource/FromSecretsManager.der"));
    
    // Convert the DER file to a Java PrivateKey
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyDerBytes);
    KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey pk = factory.generatePrivate(spec);

    // Use PemWriter to write the key to PEM format
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    try (PemWriter pw = new PemWriter(sw)) {
        PemObjectGenerator gen = new JcaMiscPEMGenerator(pk);
        pw.writeObject(gen);
    }
    String privateKeyPem = sw.toString();
```

Comment: How to convert private key to der format?